# Unable to run D-Link DWA-127 rev B1 on Kali linux

Tags: drivers, kali-linux

lsusb lists it as 2001:3d04
How do i install drivers?
Please help

Output from 
`lsmod |grep mt7601u`

`mt7601u 98304 0 mac80211 638976 1 mt7601u cfg80211 573440 2 mac80211,mt7601u usbcore 241664 5' uhci_hcd,mt7601u,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid`

Output from `ifconfig -a`

`eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 inet 192.168.146.129 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.146.255 inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fed0:5896 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link> ether 00:0c:29:d0:58:96 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) RX packets 38 bytes 4096 (4.0 KiB) RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 TX packets 38 bytes 3691 (3.6 KiB) TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0`

`lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host> loop txqueuelen 1 (Local Loopback) RX packets 18 bytes 1058 (1.0 KiB) RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 TX packets 18 bytes 1058 (1.0 KiB) TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0`

Output from `dmesg` : [screenshot link](https://prnt.sc/iukbef)

Comment: You can try this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/629440/d-link-dwa-127-rev-b1-not-working  and update this questions for specifics to your problem should this not fix your issue.  Also if you have tried this or other things please reference that you put some work into troubleshooting to decrease people downvoting your questions.

Comment: Please learn how to format your text. That is not how `ifconfig -a` presents its information. The easier you make it for us to help you, the more likely we will choose to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my adapter to work by following this tutorial  [link](https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a recent-enough kernel, you might already have the necessary drivers:

```
$ modinfo mt7601u |grep -i '2001.3d04'
alias:          usb:v2001p3D04d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
$ _
```

For Debian, the `mt7601u` firmware is in `firmware-misc-nonfree`. Since you're using Kali, I assume something similar is available for your system.

Comment: modinfo shows i have it.Ill try to find it.What to do next? Sry im complete noob.

Comment: This is the output.  
'mt7601u                98304  0
mac80211              638976  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              573440  2 mac80211,mt7601u
usbcore               241664  5' uhci_hcd,mt7601u,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid
But it doesnt show up under ifconfig -a  nor iwconfig.